# Build process fails with Invalid data, chunk must be a string or buffer, not object

Tags: android, build

while building the android version, i get this error: 'Invalid data, chunk must be a string or buffer, not object'.
What I tried:

1. Removing platform android and added it again
2. Deleted the platform directory and let ionic add it again
3. Update Ionic and Cordova
4. all the other tips i found in the www.

Nothing helped. I get this error since hrs and waste a lot of time with that.

I do NOT use firebase or the `cordova-plugin-fcm`.
Ionic info return this: Ionic:

```
 ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.0 (C:\Users\lars\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11
```

Cordova:

```
 cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 6.4.0
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic 5.0.8, cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.0.3, (and 17 other plugins)
```

System:

```
 Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
   NodeJS            : v8.11.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.1.0
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Environment:

```
ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\lars\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

How do I get rid of the error, I mentioned above?